# Properly dispose of event producer from a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

This is SIMPLIFIED code just illustrating a problem I am trying to solve (haven't compiled it so please ignore any syntax errors). Suppose I have a ProducerProxy like:

```
public class ProducerProxy : IDisposable {
   public event EventHandler<EventArgs> NotificationEvent;
   private volatile bool itsKeepProducing = true;

   public DoStuff() {
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        while (itsKeepProducing) { 
            RaiseNotificationEvent();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
      }
    }

   public void Dispose() {
      itsKeepProducing = false;
      DestroySomeStuff();
   }
}
```

Suppose I now have a class that uses this ProducerProxy:

```
public class Consumer : IDisposable {
    private ProducerProxy itsProducerProxy;

    public void Consumer() {
        itsProducerProxy = new ProducerProxy();
        itsProducerProxy.NotificationEvent += OnNotificationEvent;
    }

    public void Start() {
         itsProducerProxy.DoStuff();
    }

    public void OnNotificationEvent(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        DealWithNotification(args);  //this could take some time maybe 1-2 seconds
    }

    public void Dispose() {
       //how do I dispose of the producer here?
       //I can't just do the following because notifications might still be processing in OnNotification event:
       if (itsProducerProxy != null) {
            itsProducerProxy.NotificationEvent -= OnNotificationEvent;
            itsProducerProxy.Dispose();
            itsProducerProxy = null;
       }
    }
```

So my use case is (yes, it should be done using `try/catch` or using `using` but that distracts from the question -- just illustrating a point)

```
var consumer = new Consumer();
consumer.Start();
... //do some stuff 
consumer.Dispose();
```

What is the correct/proper thread-safe implementation for `Consumer.Dispose()`? or maybe for `Producer.Dispose()`?

Comment: `//this could take some time maybe 1-2 seconds` could this understand that a disposal might be happening during the process?  Can it check a CancellationToken while doing its work, understanding when IsCancellationRequested is true, the object is disposed and it's time to stop work?

Comment: @Will, yes, disposal could be happening while the event is being processed. Feel free to post a solution using a CancellationToken.

Comment: Probably the safest thing would be simply to make sure that your `EventArgs` carries all the required state with it. Then it doesn't matter if a disposal happens mid-processing. Really depends on how much you're relying on `ProducerProxy` within your handler, though.

Comment: You can't dispose the producer, it never stops.  And you can't be sure that you are the only consumer so it is also fundamentally unsafe.  Any scenario where the producer outlives the consumer makes using events less than ideal.  Better then to do it the other way around, register the consumer with the producer and have the producer call a method.  Unregister when you don't want to consume anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant - good catch. Made the change in the question to show you can indeed stop the ProducerProxy

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot - please feel free to post a solution. Would love to see that approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cooperative thread cancellation pattern by passing in a CancellationToken into your process...

```
public class Consumer : IDisposable {    
    private ProducerProxy itsProducerProxy;

    // how we signal others that we are disposed
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    /*  SNIP  */

    public void OnNotificationEvent(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        // We now provide the inner process with the cancellation token
        DealWithNotification(_cts.Token); 
    }

    public void Dispose() 
    {
        // not thread safe but you get the gist
        if (_cts!= null) {
            _cts.Cancel();
            _cts.Dispose();
            _cts = null;
        }
        /*  SNIP  */
    }
}
```

where the inner process short circuits when cancellation has been requested

```
private void DealWithNotification(CancellationToken token)
{
    if(token.IsCancellationRequested) return;
    var foo = "omgwtflol" + bar;
    if(token.IsCancellationRequested) return;
    Thread.Sleep(2);
    if(token.IsCancellationRequested) return;
    var reallyEveryTime = File.ReadAllBytes(foo);
    if(token.IsCancellationRequested) return;
    foreach(var b in reallyEveryTime)
    {
        if(token.IsCancellationRequested) return;
        InnerProcess(token); 
    }
    // etc etc etc you get the idea
}
```

Comment: I don't think this would be thread-safe because once you check the cancellationtoken in DealWithNotification it might have just been set right after your check but before your next statement executes. Maybe the token needs to be checked in a locking-type manner in `OnNotificationEvent` before executing `DealWithNotification`?

Comment: @Denis It's called *"cooperative thread cancellation"* for a reason.  You have to cooperate.  It **is** thread safe, in the meaning that `IsCancellationRequested` won't throw if you access it from multiple threads and there is no race condition between threads reading it and threads calling `Cancel()` on the token source.  There is, of course, no guarantee that one tick when you check it the value is false and the very next tick it's now true.  If you must cancel the current instruction on dispose, this pattern is not suitable for you. Think about thread isolation and using Abort() to cancel.